# getJson não está funcionando

Tags: javascript, json

acho que é algum problema aqui: `api/combobox_cidades.php?search=`, se eu colocar o arquivo php `combobox_cidades.php` na pasta principal (escrevendo somente: `$.getJSON('combobox_cidades.php?search='`), funciona. agora se eu deixar na pasta `api/meuarquivo.php` e redirecionar para ela, não funciona.

esse javascript está na pasta `js/main.js`

```
$('#cod_estados').on('change',function(){
    var valor = $(this).val(); 

    if( valor ) {
        $.getJSON('api/combobox_cidades.php?search=',{cod_estados: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}, function(resultado){
            var options = '<option value=""></option>';

            for (var i = 0; i < resultado.length; i++) {
                options += '<option value="' + resultado[i].cod_cidades + '">' + resultado[i].nome + '</option>';
            }
            $('#cod_cidades').html(options).show();
        });
    } else {
        $('#cod_cidades').html('<option value="">– Escolha um estado –</option>');
    }
});
```

eu tenho uma query que preenche os dados dentro de um campo e ela funciona,  passei a url certinho como fiz no anterior e funciona.

```
//preenche os dados para o campo select
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    url: 'api/especialidade.php',
    success: function(retorno){
        for(var i=0;i <retorno.length; i++){
            $('td select#cod_especialidade').append("<option value='"+retorno[i].cod_especialidade+"'>"+retorno[i].nome+"</option>");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Já tentou um caminho relativo à raiz? `/api/...`?

Comment: Tens isso online? experimenta esse URL no endereço do browser diretamente até funcionar, e testa o que o bfavaretto sugeriu. Comenta aqui se funcionou.